# GroupBy() isn't working as expected unless I first load the individual items into memory

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following query and I'm expecting a number of results. But I get only one result.

```
var results = await DbContext.Trucks
    .Where(t => t.Departure.HasValue)
    .Select(t => new
    {
        t.Departure!.Value.Year,
        t.Departure!.Value.Month,
        Quantity = t.InboundQuantity + t.ToTransfers.Sum(x => x.Quantity) - t.FromTransfers.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
    })
    .GroupBy(t => new { t.Year, t.Month })
    .ToDictionaryAsync(g => new DateTime(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, 1), g => g.Sum(x => x.Quantity));
```

*Results*

```
results Count = 1
+ [0]   {[{7/1/2021 12:00:00 AM}, 3842405714]}
```

If I rewrite the query to load all the rows into memory and then group, I then get the expected number of results.

```
var test = DbContext.Trucks
    .Where(t => t.Departure.HasValue)
    .Select(t => new
    {
        t.Departure!.Value.Year,
        t.Departure!.Value.Month,
        Quantity = t.InboundQuantity + t.ToTransfers.Sum(x => x.Quantity) - t.FromTransfers.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
    })
    .ToList();

var test2 = test
    .GroupBy(t => new { t.Year, t.Month })
    .ToDictionary(g => new DateTime(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, 1), g => g.Sum(x => x.Quantity));
```

*Results*

```
test2   Count = 27
+ [0]   {[{1/1/2022 12:00:00 AM}, 95309170]}
+ [1]   {[{2/1/2022 12:00:00 AM}, 79737674]}
+ [2]   {[{3/1/2022 12:00:00 AM}, 173875538]}
+ [3]   {[{7/1/2021 12:00:00 AM}, 125219196]}
+ [4]   {[{8/1/2021 12:00:00 AM}, 110993954]}
+ [5]   {[{10/1/2021 12:00:00 AM}, 129282632]}
+ [6]   {[{11/1/2021 12:00:00 AM}, 160927222]}
+ [7]   {[{12/1/2021 12:00:00 AM}, 117813444]}
+ [8]   {[{9/1/2021 12:00:00 AM}, 26260420]}
+ [9]   {[{4/1/2022 12:00:00 AM}, 161695966]}
+ [10]  {[{5/1/2022 12:00:00 AM}, 184781001]}
+ [11]  {[{6/1/2022 12:00:00 AM}, 146985217]}
+ [12]  {[{7/1/2022 12:00:00 AM}, 84260160]}
+ [13]  {[{8/1/2022 12:00:00 AM}, 89769875]}
+ [14]  {[{10/1/2022 12:00:00 AM}, 187958697]}
+ [15]  {[{11/1/2022 12:00:00 AM}, 175034225]}
+ [16]  {[{9/1/2022 12:00:00 AM}, 108421771]}
+ [17]  {[{1/1/2023 12:00:00 AM}, 179720773]}
+ [18]  {[{12/1/2022 12:00:00 AM}, 110000415]}
+ [19]  {[{2/1/2023 12:00:00 AM}, 210461751]}
+ [20]  {[{3/1/2023 12:00:00 AM}, 232239876]}
+ [21]  {[{4/1/2023 12:00:00 AM}, 176482465]}
+ [22]  {[{5/1/2023 12:00:00 AM}, 218732769]}
+ [23]  {[{6/1/2023 12:00:00 AM}, 186324324]}
+ [24]  {[{7/1/2023 12:00:00 AM}, 151700649]}
+ [25]  {[{8/1/2023 12:00:00 AM}, 142653374]}
+ [26]  {[{9/1/2023 12:00:00 AM}, 75763156]}
```

I might be missing something stupid here but I'm at a loss to explain this.

Why is the first query not working as expected?

##### Update

If anyone's curious, I got this query to work correctly using the following syntax. Note the second parameter to `GroupBy()` and a minor change to the `ToDictionaryAsync()` call.

```
var results = await query
    .Where(t => t.Departure.HasValue)
    .Select(t => new
    {
        t.Departure!.Value.Year,
        t.Departure!.Value.Month,
        Quantity = t.InboundQuantity + t.ToTransfers.Sum(x => x.Quantity) - t.FromTransfers.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
    })
    .GroupBy(t => new { t.Year, t.Month }, x => x.Quantity)
    .ToDictionaryAsync(g => new DateTime(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, 1), g => g.Sum());
```

Comment: Try to move `g.Sum(x => x.Quantity)` in `Select`. Grouping should be followed by `Select`, in your case you call `ToDictionary`.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: If I group before the select, I get an error that the expression cannot be translated.

Comment: In first example you do not have Year and Month defined so following will not work : new { t.Year, t.Month }  It should be Year = t.Departure!.Value.Year, Month = t.Departure!.Value.Month,

Comment: @jdweng: I think you are mistaken about that. It compiles fine. The code is able to determine the name from the property assigned to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping has no seance without aggregation, `ToDictionaryAsync` is trying to enumerate `IGrouping<,>` on the client side. Add additional `Select` before calling `ToDictionaryAsync`:

```cs
var results = await DbContext.Trucks
    .Where(t => t.Departure.HasValue)
    .Select(t => new
    {
        t.Departure!.Value.Year,
        t.Departure!.Value.Month,
        Quantity = t.InboundQuantity + t.ToTransfers.Sum(x => x.Quantity) - t.FromTransfers.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
    })
    .GroupBy(t => new { t.Year, t.Month })
    .Select(g = new 
    { 
        g.Key.Year, 
        g.Key.Month,
        Quantity = g => g.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
    })
    .ToDictionaryAsync(x => new DateTime(x.Year, x.Month, 1), g => x.Quantity);
```

Update, since here we have EF Core SQL generation limitation, prepared workaround:

```cs
var trucks = DbContext.Trucks
    .Where(t => t.Departure.HasValue);

var toSummary = 
    from t in trucks
    from tr in t.ToTransfers
    group tr by new
    {
        t.Departure!.Value.Year,
        t.Departure!.Value.Month,        
    } into g
    select new 
    {
        g.Key.Year,
        g.Key.Month,
        ToQuantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
    };

var fromSummary = 
    from t in trucks
    from tr in t.FromTransfers
    group tr by new
    {
        t.Departure!.Value.Year,
        t.Departure!.Value.Month,        
    } into g
    select new 
    {
        g.Key.Year,
        g.Key.Month,
        FromQuantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
    };

var query = 
    from t in trucks
    from to in toSummary
        .Where(to => t.Year == t.Departure!.Value.Year && t.Month == t.Departure!.Value.Month)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    from f in fromSummary
        .Where(f => f.Year == t.Departure!.Value.Year && f.Month == t.Departure!.Value.Month)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new 
    {
        g.Key.Year, 
        g.Key.Month,
        Quantity = t.InboundQuantity + ((int?)to.ToQuantity) ?? 0 - ((int?)f.FromQuantity) ?? 0
    }


var results = await query
    .ToDictionaryAsync(x => new DateTime(x.Year, x.Month, 1), g => x.Quantity);
```

Comment: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.'

Comment: Well, here you have SQL Server limitation which EF Core not handled.. We can rewrite this query.

Comment: What is strange to me is that I understand when it tells me it cannot translate the expression. But how can it compile and run but just give the wrong results? That seems like a bug.

Comment: EF Core has a tons of bugs, i think for this one they have issue.